# Setting text in facebook statuc from native android application

Tags: android, post, status

I am trying to set text in facebook status from my app, but its not copying in the status dialog box of facebook post dialog box. Dialog box is opening correctly for fb, but message is not copied in the status box. Thanks
My code is :

```
facebook = new Facebook("my_app_id");
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", "HI there");


        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", parameters,
                new PostDialogListener());

PostDialogListener class
                public  class PostDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the text posted on Facebook after you click "Post"?

Comment: I have to manually write text is status box to post. I want it to be feed from my application

Comment: @sanjeev See my answer it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and see if it does the job for you. For me it works perfectly because i want to post a custom message.

```
new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                parameters.putString("message", "your_message_here");

            parameters.putString("caption", "your_caption");
            try {
                mFacebook.request("me");
                String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("")
                        || response.equals("false") || response.startsWith("{\"error\"")) {
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(failRunnable);
                } else {
                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(successRunnable);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

mFacebook is my Facebook Object.